# Does the cyclic property of the trace hold within analytic functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, trace

It's well known that for finite-dimensional linear operators $A$ and $B$, $\mathrm{tr}(AB) = \mathrm{tr}(BA)$, from which it follows that the trace of a product of multiple matrices is left invariant under arbitrary cyclic permutations.

Furthermore, we have that
$$\mathrm{tr}\left[ (AB)^n \right] = \mathrm{tr} [ \underbrace{AB AB \dots AB}_{\text{$n$ times}} ] = \mathrm{tr}[ \underbrace{BA BA \dots BA}_{\text{$n$ times}}] = \mathrm{tr}\left[ (BA)^n \right],$$

and so by linearity we should have than $\mathrm{tr}[f(AB)] = \mathrm{tr}[f(BA)]$ for any analytic function $f$, as long as both arguments lie within the domain of convergence. And more generally, this result should extend to arbitrary cyclic permutations of the matrices in the argument of $f$.

1. Is it true that $\mathrm{tr}[f(ABC\dots)]$ is invariant under any cyclic permutation of the matrices in the argument of $f$, as long as both matrix products lie within the domain of convergence of the Maclaurin series for $f$?
2. Is it possible for a cyclic permutation of the matrices to move the product in or out of the domain of convergence?
3. Does the story change if we consider infinite-dimensional trace-class linear operators instead of finite-dimensional ones?

Comment: The result for cyclic permutations of $n$ matrices follows from that for two: e.g. writing
$A_1 \ldots A_k = B$ and $A_{k+1} \ldots A_n = C$, we have $A_1 \ldots A_n = BC$ and
$A_{k+1} \ldots A_n A_1 \ldots A_k = CB$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yeah, that's what I said in my first sentence.

Answer (score 3):

$AB$ and $BA$ always have the same nonzero eigenvalues, and these should determine the convergence of the series for $f$ at $AB$
and $BA$.

Comment: That's assuming it's analytic about 0 specifically? What about a function like log or $1/z$?

Comment: Should apply to series about any point.

Comment: Note also that analytic continuation can be used.  So since $\text{tr}(log(1+t A B)) = \text{tr}(\log(1+tBA))$ for sufficiently small $|t|$, and both sides are analytic in $t$, they are equal for all $t$ for which $1+tAB$ is nonsingular (with proper attention paid to branches of log).